# How can I simplify 2 methods with only Parameter different?

Tags: java

I have 2 methods with exactly same body. Only the second parameter (Class or TypeReference) is different. How can I make one method out of this or at least extract the body so it is not duplicated ?
Thanks.

```
public static <T> T mapResponseBody(ApiException e, Class<T> type) {
    T result = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    try {
        result = objectMapper.readValue(e.getResponseBody(), type);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        log.error("Json Mapper Error",ioException);
    }
    return result;
}



 public static <T> T mapResponseBodyArray(ApiException e, TypeReference<T> type) {
    T result = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    try {
        result = objectMapper.readValue(e.getResponseBody(), type);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        log.error("Json Mapper Error",ioException);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In your method with `TypeReference` you can transform type to `Class` and call the other method and return the result from it. Like this: `Class<?> typeClass = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(type).getRawClass();     mapResponseBody(e, typeClass);`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you take a look at it. One method will have the functionality while the other methods will act as a helper to use. We cannot ignore the variable 'Class and TypeReference' because it is used in the objectMapper.

```
public static <T> T mapResponseBody(ApiException e, Class<T> typeClass , TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
    T result = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    try {
        if(typeClass != null){
            result = objectMapper.readValue(e.getResponseBody(), typeClass);
        }else{
            result = objectMapper.readValue(e.getResponseBody(), typeReference);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.out.println("Json Mapper Error : " + ioException);
    }
    return result;
}
public static <T> T mapResponseBody(ApiException e, Class<T> typeClass) {
    return mapResponseBody(e, typeClass, null);
}

public static <T> T mapResponseBody(ApiException e, TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
    return mapResponseBody(e, null, typeReference);
}
```

Comment: Definitely 1 solution. But not sure if there is a better one.

Comment: I don't know if it is a good design to have 1 parameter which is null and acts as a switch but is not a boolean.

Comment: @Toni26 yep it is. it is just like a method with default parameters when you do not give any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method with TypeReference where you will transform it in Class and call the other method.

```
public static <T> T mapResponseBody(ApiException e, Class<T> type) {
    T result = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    try {
        result = objectMapper.readValue(e.getResponseBody(), type);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        log.error("Json Mapper Error",ioException);
    }
    return result;
}



public static <T> T mapResponseBodyArray(ApiException e, TypeReference<T> type) {

    Class<T> typeClass = (Class<T>) TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(type).getRawClass();

    return mapResponseBody(e, typeClass);

}
```

Comment: Does not work . Error message: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that capture of ? conforms to T

Comment: @Toni26, You are right, I changed my answer. I had typeClass as <?> and I changed it with <T> and also added the cast `(Class<T>)`